# Python.Paho: Publish a message to Topic A after receiving a message from Topic B

Tags: python, python-3.x, mqtt, paho

Trying to publish a message to Topic A upon receiving a message on Topic B, but I am getting an error:

> AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'publish'

The problem stems from my `on_message` function, specifically the addition of this single line (removing the line remedies the problem):

```
client.publish("TOPIC/A", payload="YES", retain=False)
```

My on_message callback function looks like this:

```
def on_message(self, client, message): 
   if(message.payload === condition): 
   client.publish("TOPIC/A", payload="YES", retain=False)
```

Is it not possible to publish a message this way?

Comment: What do you expect `client` to be?

Comment: the value of `client` is None. The error message is self-descriptive.

Comment: I expected my client to be the client that is connected to my MQTT server... The one that is currently receiving the messages.

Answer (score -1):

On_message() is a static function with Signaturen (Client, Userdata, topic).  In a Class you can usw decorator @staticmethod